# Kial la Akademio mem elektas siajn anojn?

Tags: esperanto-speakers

Ŝajnas pli juste al mi, ke ĉiuj Esperantistoj kiuj havas sufiĉan lingvonivelon aŭ sufiĉan aktivecon en la lingvo elekti la Akademianojn.

Kiel ĉi tiu nuna sistemo fariĝis? Ĉu ĝi jam ekzistis por la lingvo komitato, la organizo kiu antaŭis la Akademion? Ĉu Zamenhof mem volis ĝin? Ĉu ekzistas movado por ŝanĝi ĝin? Kial ĝi estas ĉi tia? Se ne estas bona kialo, kial restas, ke Akademianoj mem povas elekti sin?

Answer (score 0):

Vi povas trovi ĉi tie, kial estraranoj de La Akademio elektiĝas:

https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/akademio/index.php?title=Kiel_fari%C4%9Di_membro_de_la_Akademio%3F

La kondutmaniero de La Akademio eldiras ke "Unu rezultas el la praktiko kaj tradicio."

La historio de La Akademio aperas ĉi tie:

https://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/akademio/index.php?title=Historio_de_la_Akademio

Nelonge, "En 1948 la Lingva Komitato kaj ĝia Akademio kunfandiĝis en unu solan korpon nomatan 'Akademio de Esperanto.'"

Kial vi preferas ĉi tiun praktikon: "...ĉiuj Esperantistoj kiuj havas sufiĉan lingvonivelon aŭ sufiĉan aktivecon en la lingvo elekti la Akademianojn." Kie estas tia registro? Mi kredas, nenie. Ne ekzistas.

Mi preferas, ke membroj de La Akademio konsistigas la plej spertajn Esperantistojn, ne la plej popolajn.

Comment: Bonvenon ĉe [esperanto.SE]! Ĉu vi vere celas "kial" (=pro kiu kaŭzo, angle "why") kie vi skribis "kial" aŭ ĉu tiuj estu "kiel" (=kia-maniere, angle "how")? Se "kiel", bonvolu redakti vian respondon pere de la ligilo [edit].

Comment: Dankon. Mi ŝanĝis mian respondon.

Comment: Kio pri "kial estraranoj de La Akademio elektiĝas"? Ĉu ne tio estu "kiel …"?

Comment: Bonvole ne uzu la iĝi-pasivon. Do anstataŭ "kial estraranoj de La Akademio elektiĝas" prefere skribu ekz. "kiel oni elektas la estraranojn de La Akademio".